# UseStartup<Startup> vs UseStartup(nameof(YourAssembly))

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

I just read that `UseStartup(nameof(YourAssembly))` will use the `Startup` class, unless you have a specific environment variable set for `Environment`, and have the corresponding `StartupEnvironment` class.

If `UseStartup(nameof(YourAssembly))` works for both scenarios, whereas `UseStartup<Startup>` only works for a `Startup` class, why would you ever use `UseStartup<Startup>` over `UseStartup(nameof(YourAssembly))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, we will just have one start up class normally. So there is no need to use `UseStartup(nameof(YourAssembly))`, since the `UseStartup<Startup>` could be more readable.

If we just have one startup class, there is no difference between the `UseStartup(nameof(YourAssembly))` and `UseStartup<Startup>`.

If we have multiple startup class, then we will use `UseStartup(nameof(YourAssembly))` instead of `UseStartup<Startup>`.

More details, you could refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-3.1#startup-class-conventions).